# (Errno 2) No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Пользователь/Downloads/Train_rev1.csv'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, error-handling, read.csv

I have a problem.

```py
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Пользователь/Downloads/Train_rev1.csv',
                   encoding='cp1252')
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Пользователь/Downloads/Train_rev1.csv'.

The file itself is located there.
What to do?

Initially, there were problems with encoding. I changed it, then tried to put

```
(r' ', encoding='cp1252')
```

but this didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Welcome! Shoudn't it be (escaped) backslashes for Windows paths? Like this: `'C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\Downloads\\Train_rev1.csv'`?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution :

1. Create a folder `data` in your working directory
2. Move the CSV file to `data` folder
3. Read the file using :

```
pd.read_csv('data/Train_rev1.csv')
```